# More than one exogenous input in NARX network in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network

In MATLAB, we can define a NARX network by the function:

```
net = narxnet(1:2,1:2,10);
```

and the network looks like:
[image]

The first `1:2` is the number of delay of `X` and the second `1:2` is the number of delay of `Y`. If I have another `Z` with the number of delay is `1:2` as well to be considered in the network, how should add it?

I tried by the code

```
net.numInputs = 3;
net.inputs{3}.name = 'Z';
```

then I have 
[image]

Now, I want to change the number of delay of `Z` in the network,

I tried

```
net.inputs{3}.feedbackOutput = 1:2;
```

then it returns

```
"net.inputs{i}.feedbackOutput" is a read only property."
```

how should I do to add the number of delay of `z` in the network. PS: I know how to connect `z` to the hidden layer.

Comment: do you just want to add an additional exogene vector with the same delays or do you really need a new input?

Comment: An additional exogene vector `z` with different delays, i.e., z_{t-1}, z_{t-2}, z_{t-3} need to be considered in the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i assume you still want only 1 output. The entire input(2) gets created when net.Output.feedbackMode is set to true, thats why ".feedbackOutput" is readonly. i think what you where searching for is "net.inputWeights{1,3}.delays". Maybe this works for you:

```
[X,T] = simpleseries_dataset;
Y=mat2cell(cellfun(@(x) x*2,X),1,ones(1,100))


net = narxnet(1:2,1:3); %classic narxnet 
net.numInputs = 3; % adding an input
net.inputConnect  =[1 1 1; 0 0 0]; %connecting 3 inputs to the first layer

%defining input 3
net.inputs{3}.name = 'Input3';
net.inputs{3}.processFcns = {'mapminmax'}; %whaterever you want, but remember to set them
net.inputWeights{1,3}.delays= 1:4; % the actual delay value for an input
view(net) %

%prepare and close
[Xs,Xi,Ai,Ts] = preparets(net,[X;Y],{},T); %train with exogene inputs
net = train(net,Xs,Ts,Xi,Ai);
net = closeloop(net);
view(net) %please note that the order of inputs is switched in the picture

%prepare and use
[Xs,Xi,Ai,Ts] = preparets(net,[X;Y],{},T);
T2 = net(Xs,Xi,Ai);

%if you want to see the results
plot(cell2mat(T(5:96)))
hold on
plot(cell2mat(T2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.